# AXI Bus security related protocol

Tags: bus

In AXI Bus protocol,
Can anyone explain me about the ARPROTS[2:0] and AWPROTS[2:0] ?
Like each bit corresponds to what?
and 
what is privileged access and non-privileged?
what is data access and instruction access?

Answer (score 1):

in AXI

AxPROTS[0] :-
privileged means some kind of administrative access, like when we update any system write access to ROM, so you can say some kind of root access.

AxPROTS[1] :-
secure means restriction, like all system has some secure addresses that addresses only access by trusted transactions, non-secure addresses access by any transactions.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch12s03s01.html

AxPROTS[2] :-
data access and instruction access, in data access you only have set of data form that you do relative operation on memory like read and write, in instruction access you know who made change in memory, in this case you know the source and what operation to be preformed.
[what is difference between instruction access and data access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800552/what-is-difference-between-instruction-access-and-data-access)

correct me if i am wrong
-Dhaval Sanepara